# Ionic Framework Braintree Integration

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal, braintree

has anyone successfully integrated Braintree on his Ionic Framework (preferably iOS) app?
I’m really confused what I need and how to setup everything correctly.

My main goal is using PayPal with Braintree since the PayPal Cordova Plugin uses `UiWebView` which won’t be accepted by Apple starting from April.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Install Braintree Ionic and Cordova plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/braintree)
2. Setup Braintree account, setup Braintree sandbox account
3. Insert PayPal Sandbox credentials in my Braintree account under “Processing Options”
4. Insert and setup the sample code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/braintree

I can run the Ionic app and also process a sample checkout via credit card.
Although if I click on “PayPal” instead choosing the credit card option, I always get the error message: `PayPal app switch is missing a returnURLScheme`.

I really don’t know how to fix that, I already checked Google, Stackoverflow but didn’t found the issue. Something seems to be missing in my config but I don’t know what.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't know enough about ionic/cordova to give you a precise solution, but I assume the issue is that the PayPal checkout needs a deeplink URL scheme to get back to your app after a PayPal checkout, so you need to configure this somewhere